# How to deal with compound words in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search-engine, information-retrieval

I know there is a good [Compound Word Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-compound-word-tokenfilter.html) in elasticsearch but my problem is kind of different. I am wondering how search engines like google deal with open form compound words like "post office" or "living room". if you type "postoffice" instead of "post office" you still get the same result. I want to have such feature in my search engine with elasticsearch. what is the solution to this problem? should I tokenize post office as one token? if it is true, HOW?